# In defining a hook_block_info() is it possible to define the region per theme?

Tags: blocks

I'm trying to avoid this [error](http://drupal.org/node/1172560) and it seems I should be able to define the blocks region on a per theme basis. I've checked the [API documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) but it's not covered. Has anyone pulled this off yet?

A for instance would be how do I additionally define the `sidebar_first` region in `Bartik` in the following example?

Here is my current `_block_info()`:

```
  $blocks['find_activities_large'] = array(
  'info' => t('Find Activities Widget (large)'),
  'status' => TRUE,
  'theme' => 'MY_CUSTOM_THEME',
  'region' => 'inner_sidebar',
  'weight' => 0,
  'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED,
  'pages' => '<front>',
```

);

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure but I would be surprised if that works.

You could try to define the region using the Context module and [Context Conditional Theme](http://drupal.org/project/context_condition_theme) module if you only want certain blocks to show up in certain regions for certain themes. Context module configuration is exportable so you could commit those settings to code.

Comment: +1 for context module here. You can use Context module + Delta module, which allow you to create variance of a theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [hook_block_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info_alter/7), which gets `$theme` as parameter. The visibility, and the region the hook sets are valid for that specific theme.

As example of implementation, you can look at [dashboard_block_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!dashboard!dashboard.module/function/dashboard_block_info_alter/7).

```
function dashboard_block_info_alter(&$blocks, $theme, $code_blocks) {
  $admin_theme = variable_get('admin_theme');
  if (($admin_theme && $theme == $admin_theme) || (!$admin_theme && $theme == variable_get('theme_default', 'bartik'))) {
    foreach ($blocks as $module => &$module_blocks) {
      foreach ($module_blocks as $delta => &$block) {
        // Make administrative blocks that are not already in use elsewhere
        // available for the dashboard.
        if (empty($block['status']) && (empty($block['region']) || $block['region'] == BLOCK_REGION_NONE) && !empty($code_blocks[$module][$delta]['properties']['administrative'])) {
          $block['status'] = 1;
          $block['region'] = 'dashboard_inactive';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```